# "'Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'row[0].val')" error in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This is the `PayScrn.js` code. When Im pressing the 'Add' button I receive "Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'row[0].val')" error present in expo. I cant understand how it happen.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View,Button} from 'react-native';

const PayScrn = props => {
    const [row, addRow] = useState([]);
    const addItem = () => {
        addRow([...row,{ val: '20', type: 'Credit card' }]);
        alert(row[0].val)
    };
    return (
        <View>
             <Button onPress={addItem} title='Add' />
        </View>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

addRow is asynchronous. To view the updated result use useEffect()

```
useEffect(() => { console.log(row)}, row)
```

Every time **row** is updated, useEffect will be called

[useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: Thank you Mr.Mubashir. Problem solved with your answer.

Comment: Happy to hear! If the answer was useful in identifying the issue, would appreciate if you'd mark it as correct :)